# How to make localhost app publish to CloudFoundry as is: getting Resource not Available on CF

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I have a basic Spring web app (Spring MVC Project) that I want to run on CloudFoundry.  I took the default HelloWorld project and added to it.  I've installed the CloudFoundry STS extensions, got a server created, publisd my app to the CF site.  The 'home' page displays both on my localhost server, and the CF servers.  All good.  But, when I click on the only link to take me back into the HomeController to a different method/view, I get a 'Resource not available' error on the CF server, though it works perfectly on my localhost (local PC) server.

On my local PC:

1. The url is: `http://localhost:8080/myapp`  (correct)
2. The initial page (home.jsp) displays with one link: `<a href="/myapp/property">Property</a>` (correct)
3. Mousing over the link shows this in the status bar:  `http://localhost:8080/myapp/property`  (correct)
4. Clicking takes me to the method mapped to `/property` and shows the property page (`property.jsp`). (correct)

On CloudFoundry:

1. The url is : `http://myapp.cloudfoundry.com/` (correct)
2. The initial page (`home.jsp`) displays same as on my localhost PC. (correct)
3. Mousing over link shows this in status bar: `http://myapp.cloudfoundry.com/myapp/property` (correct, I think).
4. Clicking gets '`esource not available`.
5. When I go up into the location window and remove `myapp` from the url, it works.

Below is all the code, but I think it's just some of my own misunderstanding of the two environments, my local PC, and CloudFoundry.  Hopefully, someone can educate me on what I'm not knowing here to get the apps to work in both environements--locally, and on CloudFoundry.

Here is the HTML for home.jsp, the initial page

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="/myspp/property">Property</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The HomeController is:

```java
package com.myapp.app;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.myapp.services.PropertyServicesImpl;

/**
* Handles requests for the application home page.
*/
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private static final String VIEW_HOME = "home";
    private static final String VIEW_PROPERTY = "property";
    private static final String ACQUISITIONS = "acquisitions";
    @Autowired private PropertyServicesImpl propertyServices;   

    /**
* Shows home view
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        return new ModelAndView(VIEW_HOME);
    }

    /**
    * Shows Property.jsp with jQuery tabs.
    */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/property", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView property(Locale locale, Model model) {
            return new ModelAndView(VIEW_PROPERTY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than putting a fixed value in your view it would be best to get the context path for the request and then adding that to the path in your view.

Add the following imports in to your Home controller;

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
```

Then in the RequestMapping method get the current request object and create a UrlPathHelper instance and get the base path for the requests context;

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
UrlPathHelper helper = new UrlPathHelper();

String baseURL = helper.getContextPath(request);
```

So, when run from vFabric locally, baseURL will be "/myapp" and when run from a Cloud Foundry instance it will be ""

All that is left is to add this to the model and use it in the view;

```
model.addAttribute("relPath", baseURL);
```

I tested this with the Spring MVC template project in STS and it worked just fine, my HomeController looked like this;

```
package com.vmware.mvctest;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.model.Request;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        UrlPathHelper helper = new UrlPathHelper();

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        String baseURL = helper.getContextPath(request);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        model.addAttribute("relPath", baseURL);

        return "home";
    }

}
```

and my view looked like this;

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world! (${relPath}) 
</h1>
<a href="${relPath}/home">home</a>
<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect!  You not only answered my question but your solution elevated my game big-time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the context path in CF is {app.name}.cloudfoundry.com and not {app.name}.cloudfoundry.com/{app.name}

Replace in your jsp the `<a href="/myapp/property">Property</a>`  with `<a href="/property">Property</a>`.

Comment: yes, this is correct, but then the link won't work when the app is run under vFabric.

Comment: I have tested the href on cloudfoundry.com and it works. Do I miss something?

Comment: It works on CloudFoundry, but Davidson is building the app using STS and VMWare vFabric so needs a way of creating a link that will work on both. Removing myapp will stop the link from working on vFabric.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You identified my problem.  The solution above works for both the localhost server on my PC, and on CloudFoundry, not to mention really opening my eyes to other ways of passing data back to JSP's, and javascripts.